# Regular Expression matching space but not any non-word character Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write such one using **javascript** that allow any char or space but not any other non-word character:

```
david johan // pass
david johan mark // pass 
david@# johan // doesn't pass
```

I have used this

```
/^(([a-zA-Z]{3,30})+[ ]+([a-zA-Z]{3,30})+)+$/
```

but it doesn't work
any suggestions ?

Comment: What's with `|` ? And have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: What do you mean by allow or matching?

Comment: Symbols are characters too.

Comment: *any suggestions ?* Yes, read a regexp intro such as [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: I have used this pattern /^(([a-zA-Z]{3,30})+[ ]+([a-zA-Z]{3,30})+)+$/ to solve it but it doesn't work , @torazaburo I read about regexp before.

Comment: I put an example to explain the issue, why do you report the question, what is the problem ?!!

Comment: Use a site like regex101.com to debug your regexp. Also, if you have a requirement such as each name being between 3 and 30 characters, please add that information to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell exactly what you're after, but I think this will do it:

`/^([a-z0-9]|\s)*$/i`

The `^` means it needs to start with the code in parentheses, and the `$` means it needs to end with one of those characters too. `*` means 0 or more of the preceding expression and the bit inside the parens means any letter in the range `a-z` or number `0-9` or (`|`) any space character, tab, new line etc (`\s`).

That should match any letter or number and it has the case insensitive flag (`i`) on it too, it also accounts for white space.

If it was okay to include `_` then you could have used `/^(\w|\s)*$/`

Comment: It would be slightly more compact to write `/^[a-z0-9\s]*$/i`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regular expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z ]*$
```

or in Javascript:

```
var re = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z ]*$');
```

Comment: I think you need to anchor this with `^` and `$`. Why would use the `RegExp` constructor instead of writing a regexp literal?

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern `\w+\s+\w+`

**[`Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/Xu5j5g/2)**

```js
console.log(/\w+\s+\w+/g.test("david johan"))
console.log(/\w+\s+\w+/g.test("david johan mark "))
console.log(/\w+\s+\w+/g.test("david@# johan"))    
console.log(/\w+\s+\w+/g.test("david @# johan"))
console.log(/\w+\s+\w+/g.test("this should not match!"));
```

Comment: *several levels* means what?

Comment: It means in several different ways. See the counter-examples I edited into your snippet.

Comment: @torazaburo see my updated snippet.i think is fixed now

Comment: What about the last test case?